# UIView frames reset when using autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uiview, autolayout

I'm facing an issue. I'm working on an app and I'm using `storyboard` with ***Autolayout*** enabled. Now on one of my `UIViewControllers` I have placed a `UIView` (say A). Now A has multiple subviews (`UIViews` to be precise). I have applied the "`Horizontally and Vertically centered`" constraint on A. The subviews inside A don't have any constraints on them.

Now in my code I have a method for animating the subviews that are inside A. Inside that method I call the `UIView's` animation method...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: delay: options: animations: completion:];
```

and animate one of the subview's inside View A. Now the problem is that these frame changes don't persist. When I modal a view controller on current view controller and then dismiss it the frames of all the subviews inside A get reset.

I searched for it and found out the problem is occuring because of ***Autolayout***. I disabled it and then tried again and everything worked well.

But what is the workaround with ***Autolayout*** enabled...?

Am I missing something...?

The interesting thing is that many posts on StackOverflow suggested that

> we should animate the constraints and NOT the frames when using autolayout.

BUT I haven't applied any constraints on the subviews that are inside View A. Constraints are only applied on View A.

Thanks.

Comment: you're asking quite a few things, including recommendations which SO discourages. Would advise that you split this into different questions and include some code samples that support the core problem

Comment: get reset to what? How do you add these views in the first place?

Answer (score 20):

For all the views that you are animating write the following code in **viewDidLoad**

```
myViewToAnimate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Do this with your autolayout on

Comment: Yeah okay... i'll try that today... and let you know if it works... thanks anyways...

Comment: I tried it. And it works. The subview started animating with autolayout on. but it prints the following warning...

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. Note If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Comment: @A.J. yes it does add constraints of its own so you need to check apples documentation on how to manage that

Comment: IT WAS DESTROYING MY WORLD!!! Thank you for the response. For the love of me I couldn't figure out why the view would continue to reset. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is Autolayout will update the views to their original position.
The Autolayout system will periodically set the position and size of every view in your view hierarchy based on the layout constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    VIEWTOFIX.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
}
```

Putting it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidLoad` got rid of the layout constraint errors for me.